# Мониторинг игровых серверов на Java

Tags: java, мониторинг

*Доброго времени суток!*

**Небольшое вступление.** Наверное многие знакомы или встречали различного рода мониторинги игровых серверов, где отображается данные о сервере: онлайн/оффлайн, кол-во игроков и другая информация. Создатели этих серверов добавляют их в список, игроки голосуют, получают бонусы и многое другое.

**Вопрос.** Возможно ли реализовать отправку запроса на сервер по ip и порту и получить похожую или частично похожую информацию используя Java и/или сторонние библиотеки? Если да, то как? Да и вообще возможна ли реализация подобного сервиса на Java?

*Заранее благодарю за любые ответы/ссылки на ответы. Хорошего дня!*

Comment: Возможно. Изучайте API серверов, которое они предоставляют для получения таких статистик. Язык программирования может быть любым. P.S. - правда, если это .Net, то наверное и клиента будет лучше писать на .Net.

Comment: @AlexeyR. Вы имеете в виду общее API серверов? По типу, что не зависит от хоста/игры и прочего?

Comment: Очень сильно зависит о того, что за игра и как запущена. Например, некоторые игры интегрированы со Steam, что позволяет искать сервера и [смотреть какую то информацию](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tym32167/arma3beclient/master/desc/9.PNG) [без авторизации](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Server_queries). Некоторые игры поддерживают [batttleye](https://www.battleye.com/), то есть при верной настройке сервера можно по паролю подключиться и управлять сервером, так работает [мой хобби проект](https://github.com/tym32167/arma3beclient) на C#, на java я думаю тоже есть подобный софт.